# Javascript change Div style

Tags: javascript

I want that `part 1` onclick div style changes and `part 2` again on click it comes back to normal. I tried doing so but I failed to achieve the `part 2` results.

Following is the Javascript code

```
function abc() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.color="red";
}
```

After clicking the test div again, color should come back to defaulr color i.e. black...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
function abc() {
    var color = document.getElementById("test").style.color;
    if (color === "red")
         document.getElementById("test").style.color="black";
    else
         document.getElementById("test").style.color="red";
}
```

Comment: in your if sentence, why not `color="black"` and `color="red"`.
you are already holding the color

Comment: @AbdullahGheith `color` is just the *name* of the variable. I could have named it `bob` or whatever I wanted. I stored the color in `color`.

Comment: I mean in the line after if and the line after else

Comment: @AbdullahGheith In those lines I am *setting* the color of an element, not *getting* a color.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});​
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/L6VqK/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Have some logic to check the color or have some flag,

```
function abc() {
    var currentColor = document.getElementById("test").style.color;

    if(currentColor == 'red'){
    document.getElementById("test").style.color="black";
    }else{
   document.getElementById("test").style.color="red";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function abc() {
    var color = document.getElementById("test").style.color;
    color = (color=="red") ? "black" : "red" ;
    document.getElementById("test").style.color= color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may check the color before you click to change it.

```
function abc(){
     var color = document.getElementById("test").style.color;
     if(color==''){
         //change
     }else{
         //change back
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple switch statement should do the trick:

```
function abc() {
    var elem=document.getElementById('test'),color;
    switch(elem.style.color) {
        case('red'):
            color='black';
            break;
        case('black'):
        default:
            color='red';
    }
    elem.style.color=color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better change the class of the element (.regular is black, .alert is red):

```
function abc(){
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  if (myDiv.className == 'alert') {
    myDiv.className = 'regular';
  } else {
    myDiv.className = 'alert';
  }
}
```