# javascript regular expression to edit css style attributes inside of an element

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript code, which will manipulate/process html content, which has inline css. I only need to make changes to css content.
I have a html code/string like this

```
<div style="height:20px;color:yellow;">&nbsp; and some special characters here</div>
<div style="width: 200px;color:red;"><p style="font-size: 20px;">some content here &gt;</p></div>
```

Now I want to add '!important' tag to css params.not to html special chars.
Result should be

```
<div style="height:20px !important;color:yellow !important;">&nbsp; and some special characters here</div>
<div style="width: 200px !important;color:red !important;"><p style="font-size: 20px !important;">some content here &gt;</p></div>
```

what is the regular expression for this?
I tried like this

```
var str='<div style="height:20px;color:yellow;">&nbsp; and some special characters here</div>
<div style="width: 200px;color:red;"><p style="font-size: 20px;">some content here &gt;</p></div>'
var str2 = str.replace(';', ' !important;')
```

result is

`<div style="height:20px !important;color:yellow !important;">&nbsp !important; and some special characters here</div>
    <div style="width: 200px !important;color:red !important;"><p style="font-size: 20px !important;">some content here &gt !important;</p></div>`

I know this not the correct one, as it replaces all semicolons(;) with " !importanr;". If some one can give me a regular expression that only changes the content inside of style, I would appreciate it.

Please note I am not doing it on a webpage/DOM.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript change Div style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071286/javascript-change-div-style)

Comment: Try getting cssText and set !important flag

Comment: Don't manipulate CSS strings using regexp. Use the APIs designed for the purpose, such as `elt.style.height = '20px !important';` Just out of curiosity, why are you adding `!important` here? You have CSS rules which use `!important` which you want to be **even more** important than? You may wish to go back and revisit your entire CSS/stylesheet design.

Comment: A regular expression is not appropriate for this kind of manipulation; use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex** `/(?=[^<>]+:|\s*")/g`

**Usage**

```
var str='<div style="height:20px;color:yellow;">&nbsp; and some special characters here</div>
<div style="width: 200px;color:red;"><p style="font-size: 20px;">some content here &gt;</p></div>'

var str2 = str.replace(/;(?=[^<>]+:|\s*")/g, ' !important;')
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bhmjapL/)

Comment: @lanka Perfect answer to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divElements = document.querySelectorAll("div"); // reference of div

var regPattern = /(?:(.*?);)/gm; // regex

for(var i = 0, len = divElements.length; i< len; i++) {


    var divElementCss = divElements[i].style.cssText; // getting the css alone


     divElementCss = divElementCss.replace(regPattern, "$1 !important;"); 
     // adding !important

     divElements[i].style.cssText = divElementCss; // replace again 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, My code will also have multiple div's and multiple styles. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Updated answer. You need to have specific class to all elements, query those elements and just loop through and replace

Comment: thanks a lot for spending time to look into this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought you wanted to do that div element. that's why provided a generic solution. If it's for just a string as in above answer str then just the replace statement with the regex is more than enough.