# Append style to div with JS

Tags: javascript, styles

I am trying to append style to a DIV with JS but for some reason I am not succeeding. 
Maybe I am doing something wrong. Here is my code

```js
document.getElementById("umnip").style("width", "70%");
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="umnip" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `style` is a property of Node, not a function. Try `document.getElementById("umnip").style.width = "70%";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript change Div style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071286/javascript-change-div-style)

Comment: You need to use the [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195329/4203289

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it. First I was not triggering the function that I want the code to be executed... wrong logic. and second this is the js that did the trick.

```
var el = document.getElementById('umnip');
el.setAttribute('style', 'width:70%;');
```

I was sure it was something simple... just needed some directions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is the better way to do it. I found some of this in other posts but this one comes up first in google search.

This part works for standard JavaScript. I am pretty sure you can use it to remove all styles as well as add/overwite.

```
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = "border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; height: 250px; width: 600px";
```

This works for jQuery only

```
    $("#" + TDDeviceTicketID).attr("style", "padding: 10px;");
    $("#" + TDDeviceTicketID).attr("class", "roundbox1");

    This works for removing it JQUERY
    $("#" + TDDeviceTicketID).removeAttr("style");
    $("#" + TDDeviceTicketID).removeAttr("class");
```