# how to access an embedded input field in type script

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, nested

i have the following md-lookup structure.

```
<md-lookup id="test" value.bind="value" options-function.bind="optionsFunction" label="pick an option"></md-lookup>
```

when the md-lookup is loaded and i inspect the element it gets populated as follows

```
<md-lookup id="test"  value.bind="value" options-function.bind="optionsFunction" label="Pick an option"au-target-id="211">
    <div style="position: relative">
        <div class="input-field au-target" ref="validationContainer" au-target-id="113">
            <input type="text" value.bind="filter &amp; debounce: debounce" ref="input" readonly.bind="readonly" blur.trigger="blur()" focus.trigger="focus()" class="au-target" au-target-id="114" id="md-lookup-1">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</md-lookup>
```

how do i create a typescript function that will add an attribute to the input class?

for example i want it to be as

```
<input style="width:100px" type="text" value.bind="filter &amp; debounce: debounce" ref="input" readonly.bind="readonly" blur.trigger="blur()" focus.trigger="focus()" class="au-target" au-target-id="114" id="md-lookup-1">
```

as you can see i added the

```
style="width:100px"
```

to the nested input.

How can i achieve this in typescript?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071286/javascript-change-div-style)

Comment: @Rubydesic no it doesnt get the input tag, i can get the md_lookup, but the nested input i cant target it. documents.getelementbyID("test") will bring up just the md-lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` to select the input with css selectors.

```
// Select an input element with a parent with class 'input-field' with a div parent with a parent with ID 'test'
const inputNode = document.querySelector("#test > div > .input-field > input")
inputNode.setAttribute("style", "width:100px")
```